# Write a set to csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

This is my set:

```
set(['description', 'title'])
```

I need this to write to a csv file in 2 columns.
My code:

```
cw = csv.writer(open("hello.csv",'w'))
cw.writerows(cols)
```

Throws an error:

```
cw.writerow(cols)
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

Add list to csv file:

```
cw.writerow(list(cols))
for row in data:
    cw.writerow([str(row.get(k,'N/A')) for k in cols])
```

Found a way to rectify this: Open a file in wb mode rather than in w mode

Comment: Your code sample and error don't match. Are you using `writerow` singular or `writerows` plural?

Comment: I am sorry. I am using writerow. Below code works. Thanks. But now I want to print a list to csv file. Added the code

Comment: Let's use the term 'write' here; you are not printing. :-) If you have a list of sets, you need to process each set.

Comment: I am getting an error: cw.writerow([str(row.get(k,'N/A')) for k in cols])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 160: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That's because you are trying to turn Unicode values into strings without explicitly encoding them. Encode explicitly: `cw.writerow([row.get(k,u'N/A').encode('utf8') for k in cols])`. This assumes that UTF8 is a suitable codec for your needs.

Comment: Thanks you so much. But it is printing everything in one line.

Comment: can you please open a **new** question for new problems? Your original question has been solved, Stack Overflow is not suitable for interactive debugging sessions. You can also come into the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) for more interactive help.

Answer (score 7):

Turn your set into a list first:

```
cw.writerow(list(cols))
```

Note that the order in which the columns are written will be arbitrary; sets, like dictionaries, have no fixed order.